# application crash on click intent

Tags: android, button, crash, intentservice

So, if it's not obvious by know am a newbie in this 
I am working  with Intent to open a new activity (Main2Activity)
everything works great as long as there is nothing going on in (Main2Activity).

The moment that i do any thing in Main2Activity it crashes,
for example:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.checkbox_diabetic)
    CheckBox diabetes;
    @BindView(R.id.firs_next_button)
    Button nextbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.firs_next_button)
    public void setNextbutton(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and:

```
package com.mhs.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.diabetes_type_spinner)
    LabelledSpinner diabetestypes;
    @BindView(R.id.checkbox_diabetic)
    CheckBox diabetes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

it works like magic and the activity open without any problems.

But as soon as i add a thing to Main2activity it crashes on clicking the next button. For example:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.diabetes_type_spinner)
    LabelledSpinner diabetestypes;
    @BindView(R.id.checkbox_diabetic)
    CheckBox diabetes;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        diabetestypes.setItemsArray(R.array.diabetes_type_list);
    }
}
```

crash report:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.mhs.myapplication, PID: 27891
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mhs.myapplication/com.mhs.myapplication.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mhs.myapplication.LabelledSpinner.setItemsArray(int)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mhs.myapplication.LabelledSpinner.setItemsArray(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.mhs.myapplication.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:22)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6248)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2437)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: post your crash

Comment: @Rahil2952 done

Comment: please add code for your custom view LabelledSpinner

Comment: thank you Mr.@Rahil2952
i am very thankful and i have solved the problem 
it was buterknife problem 
i just converted back to old school

Comment: Could you add your solution as answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Butter Knife doesn't bind the views magically. You have to add

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

to `Main2Activity` as well. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    ButterKnife.bind(this); // Need to add this!
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
```

Comment: okay thanks you for your input
have tried that and didn't work

Comment: Well, there's also the possibility that you don't have the view in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

@tynn

so instead of doing

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.diabetes_type_spinner)
    LabelledSpinner diabetestypes;
    @BindView(R.id.checkbox_diabetic)
    CheckBox diabetes;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        diabetestypes.setItemsArray(R.array.diabetes_type_list);
    }
}
```

I did

```js
package com.mhs.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        LabelledSpinner diabetess_type = (LabelledSpinner) findViewById(R.id.diabetes_type_spinner);
        diabetess_type.setItemsArray(R.array.diabetes_type_list);
        diabetess_type.setColor(R.color.white);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.diabetes_layout);
        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

        }

    }

}
```

and surprise surprise, it works